# After reloadRowsAtIndexPaths Custom UITableViewCell appearance doesn't change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell created in a .xib and add it to a TableView. The cell contains a Button to download some data. On Button click the download starts and the Button disappears to show a cancel Button and a custom View with a download progress. After the download is finished I update my model and reload the rows in the visible area of the app.

When I debug, I see that the cellForRowAtIndexPath-methode get called and the model got updated. This means the cancel-Button and the progress-View get set hidden = YES; But they don't disappear. After I scroll the cell out of view and back in, the progress-View is hidden but the cancel-Button not.

**The TableView Methodes:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath{
 static NSString *cellIdentifierHeaderCell = @"PodcastListHeaderCell";
 static NSString *cellIdentifierBodyCell = @"PodcastListBodyCell";


// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];



if(indexPath.row == 0) {
    MGPodcastListHeaderCell *cell = (MGPodcastListHeaderCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierHeaderCell];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
          ...

    }
    return cell;
}
else {
    MGPodcastListBodyCell *cell = (MGPodcastListBodyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierBodyCell];
    if (cell == nil) {
        UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MGPodcastListBodyCell" bundle:nil];
        cell = (MGPodcastListBodyCell *)controller.view;
        NSMutableDictionary *mediaIntem = self.mediaData[(NSUInteger) (indexPath.row-1)];
        cell.mediaTitleLabel.text = mediaIntem[@"title"];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:mediaIntem[@"pubDate"]];
        cell.pubDateLabel.text = [date descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
        cell.durationLabel.text = mediaIntem [@"duration"];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton;
        cell.podcastId = (NSInteger) (indexPath.row-1);
        cell.cellPlayState = [[MGPlayState alloc] initWithPlayState:(NSInteger) [mediaIntem[@"playState"] integerValue]];
        [cell setPodcastCellDelegate:self];
    }
    return cell;
  }
}


-(void) downloadButtonPressedOfCell:(NSInteger)podcastId {

APConnection *con = [[APConnection alloc] init];
BOOL reachable = [con reachableHost];
if (reachable)
{


    //============Get Media Item =============================
    NSMutableDictionary *mediaDict = self.mediaData[(NSUInteger)podcastId];

    MGPlayState *pl_state = [[MGPlayState alloc] initWithPlayState:[[mediaDict objectForKey:@"playState"] integerValue]];

    NSString *urlString = [mediaDict objectForKey:@"mediaLink"];

    /// Finde Pathname
    NSString *fileName = [urlString lastPathComponent];
    NSLog(@"LastFileComponent: %@", fileName);
    NSString *pathName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                                                    [APFilePath getMediaContentFolder],
                                                    fileName];

    /// Request und Operation
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:pathName
                                                               append:NO];


    //// save Operation for cancle
    NSMutableDictionary *operationDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [operationDict setObject:operation
                      forKey:@"operation"];
    [operationDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:podcastId]
                      forKey:@"myIndexPath"];
    [operationDict setObject:[mediaDict objectForKey:@"mediaLink"]
                      forKey:@"mediaLink"];

    [[self operationDictArr] addObject:operationDict];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
            {
                NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:podcastId+1 inSection:0];
                MGPodcastListBodyCell *myCell = (MGPodcastListBodyCell *) [self.podcastListTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];

                [pl_state setToPlayState:PlayStateDefaultDownloadFinished];
                myCell.cellPlayState = pl_state;


                //============ Get mediaItem =============================
                self.mediaData[(NSUInteger)podcastId][@"playState"] = @4;


                /// remove operation from dict
                [[self operationDictArr] removeObject:operationDict];

                [self.podcastListTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.podcastListTable indexPathsForVisibleRows]
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                [self.podcastListTable setNeedsDisplay];
            }
                                     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
                                     {
                                         NSLog (@"Error downloadMovie: %@", error);
                                     }];

    [operation start];

}

else
{
    [EZToastView showToastMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"keineVerbindungKey", "")
                    withAlignment:EZToastViewAlignmentCenter];
}
}
```

**Custom Cell:**

```
////  MGPodcastListBodyCell.h
@protocol MGPodcastCellDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void) downloadButtonPressedOfCell: (NSInteger) podcastId;
-(void) cancleDownloadButtonPressedOfCell: (NSInteger) podcastId;
@end


@interface MGPodcastListBodyCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, retain) id <MGPodcastCellDelegate> podcastCellDelegate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mediaTitleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *durationLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *downloadMediaButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cancelMediaDownloadButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MGProgressDownloadView *progressDownloadView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *pubDateLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MGPlayState *cellPlayState;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger podcastId;

- (IBAction) downloadButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction) cancleMediaDownloadButonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
@end



//MGPodcastListBodyCell.m
@implementation MGPodcastListBodyCell

@synthesize cellPlayState = _cellPlayState;

- (void)setCellPlayState:(MGPlayState *) cellPlayState {
    _cellPlayState = cellPlayState;
    [self playStateChanged];
}


- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self setup];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setup
{
    UIView *customBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    customBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [APAppearence sharedInstance].tableCellBackgroundColorMB;
    self.backgroundView = customBackgroundView;

    self.mediaTitleLabel.textColor = [APAppearence sharedInstance].tableCellMainlabelTextColorMB;
    self.durationLabel.textColor = [APAppearence sharedInstance].standardDarkGrayColorMB;
    self.tintColor = [APAppearence sharedInstance].tableCellMainlabelTextColorMB;

    [self playStateChanged];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void) playStateChanged {
    self.downloadMediaButton.hidden = self.cellPlayState.playButtonHidden;
    [self.downloadMediaButton setNeedsDisplay];
    self.cancelMediaDownloadButton.hidden = self.cellPlayState.cancelButtonHidden;
    [self.cancelMediaDownloadButton setNeedsDisplay];
    self.progressDownloadView.hidden = self.cellPlayState.progressViewHidden;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (IBAction) downloadButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.podcastCellDelegate downloadButtonPressedOfCell: self.podcastId];
}
- (IBAction) cancleMediaDownloadButonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.podcastCellDelegate cancleDownloadButtonPressedOfCell: self.podcastId];
}

@end
```

So if somebody can tell me, what to do more than reload the cell to update the View I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you reload the cell you have code as follows...

```
MGPodcastListBodyCell *cell = (MGPodcastListBodyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierBodyCell];
if (cell == nil) {
  ....
}
```

In your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath{`
 method. Because the cell is being reused the `cell` won't be nil the second time around and therefore isn't being updated with any new information.

You need to do something when the `cell` is not nil to refresh it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. When I debug, the debugger jumps in the if-statement. So I thought the cell is nil. But nonetheless I commented out the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, so every time a new cell got created (If I'm not mistaken). But this doesn't do any thing. Do I understand something wrong?

Comment: You should always use dequeueResuable where you can as that helps with performance. If you are saying that its never reusing then that isn't the issue

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug. It wasn't a problem with the reloadRowAtIndexPath method. It was a concurrency problem.  The download finish state got overwritten by the download progress thread just at the end of downloading and the state was set back to download.

So, thank you all for your help.